# Assign a value to user custom field based on user role

Tags: php, wordpress

in Wordpress I have created user custom field "wpcf-shop-hodnota-bodu-01". Now I need to assign a value to this field based on logged-in user's role (e.g. for Administrator role the value should be "500", for Shop Manager role the value should be "350",...). Also, when user changes his/her role, the value should be updated as well.

I have managed this, and it is as far as I go...

```
add_action('show_user_profile', 'my_add_extra_profile_fields');
function my_add_extra_profile_fields($user) 
{
    if ($user->has_cap('administrator'))
    {update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'wpcf-shop-hodnota-bodu-01', '900' );}

}
```

But with this solution the change is triggered only when user displays his/her user profile. I need this change to be executed each time I save the functions.php file...

Any help, please?

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, if anyone interested the solution that worked for me: change the action to trigger after user login:

```
function my_add_extra_profile_fields($user_login, $user) 
{
    if ($user->has_cap('administrator'))
    {update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'wpcf-shop-hodnota-bodu-01', '900' );}
}
add_action('wp_login', 'my_add_extra_profile_fields', 10, 2);
```